# Javascript http to websocket upgrade

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, upgrade

I haven't been able to find a simple example for this, but I need to send an http upgrade request with headers to upgrade to a websocket.  Is the process basically to send an http request followed by a subsequent websocket instantiation? If someone has an example of how to do this in javascript it would be most helpful, thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser?  If so, the browser does all the protocol work for you.  It isn't something you do yourself.

Comment: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: ... and if you're doing it in Node.js, then best use a WebSocket library. Others have done the work for you.